# Cannot run puma with systemd on debian while the same start command in terminal works (fe_sendauth: no password supplied error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, debian, systemd, puma

I try to manage Puma server on my ruby on rails web-site with systemd. Puma cannot start with following error: *PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied*. When I start Puma myself in terminal with the same start command as in systemd it run correctly. Please help.

I use RoR 4.2.11.1, postgresql 11.2, on Debian 9.12, which run on VirtualBox 6.0.

web-site file structure:

```
/mytarifs/current - symlink to last release
/mytarifs/releases - relseas
/mytarifs/shared - shared files like database connections
```

I start Puma in terminal with success by following command:

```
        root@mt-staging-1:/mytarifs/current# bundle exec puma -C config/puma.production.rb
```

Database_URL environment variable:

```
        DATABASE_URL=postgresql://login_name:password@localhost:5432/db_tarif
```

With this database url I can connect to my db with psql

error log:

```
        Mar 07 02:20:39 mt-staging-1 systemd[1]: Started puma for mytarifs (production).
        Mar 07 02:20:40 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: [12237] Puma starting in cluster mode...
        Mar 07 02:20:40 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: [12237] * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.3.8-p459), codename: Mysterious Traveller
        Mar 07 02:20:40 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: [12237] * Min threads: 0, max threads: 5  
        Mar 07 02:20:40 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: [12237] * Environment: production
        Mar 07 02:20:40 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: [12237] * Process workers: 1
        Mar 07 02:20:40 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: [12237] * Preloading application
        Mar 07 02:20:47 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will be
        Mar 07 02:20:47 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: removed as of version 1.0.
        Mar 07 02:20:47 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: You should use PG::Connection, PG::Result, and PG::Error instead, respectively.
        Mar 07 02:20:47 mt-staging-1 puma[12237]: Called from /mytarifs/releases/20200306184828/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
```

/mytarifs/current/config/puma.production.rb

```
threads Integer(ENV['MIN_THREADS']  || 0), Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5) 

        workers Integer(ENV['PUMA_WORKERS'] || 1) 
        preload_app! 

        bind 'unix:///mytarifs/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock'
        pidfile '/mytarifs/shared/tmp/pids/puma.production.pid'
        state_path '/mytarifs/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state'

        rackup DefaultRackup 
        environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'production' 

        on_worker_boot do 
          ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do 
            ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
          end 
        end
```

/mytarifs/current/config/database.yml

```
        default: &default
          adapter: postgresql
          encoding: unicode
          pool: 125
          username: <%= ENV["PG_USERNAME"] %>
          password: <%= ENV["PG_PASSWORD"] %>
          host: localhost
          template: template0
          reconnect: true

        production:
          <<: *default
          url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
```

/etc/systemd/system/puma.service

```
        [Unit]
        Description=puma for mytarifs (production)
        After=network.target

        [Service]
        Type=simple
        Environment=RAILS_ENV=production
        Environment=PUMA_DEBUG=1
        WorkingDirectory=/mytarifs/current
        ExecStart=/root/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec puma -e production -C config/puma.production.rb
        ExecReload=/bin/kill -TSTP $MAINPID
        ExecStop=/bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID
        User=root
        Group=root

        RestartSec=1
        Restart=on-failure

        SyslogIdentifier=puma

        [Install]
         WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the reason for mistake. It is because environment variables are not available (equal to "") when systemd executes.
I do not know how get environment variables from memory, but systemd can take them from file with directive EnvironmentFile=/absolute/path/to/environment/file